# Creating custom cell content in ng-grid with multiple links - making ng-click work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I have an interesting requirement for using ng-grid, where a cell could have multiple links within, separated by a comma.  While I'm able to render the content in the cell, the ng-click action is not working.  I'm using a directive to create the links.  This is where I think the problem is, but I just don't know enough about how directives work to fix this issue.

Here's a plunker of my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/xFLzHPpmwcrEdM3eyRN5?p=preview

Controller code with directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "0": "Hemogloben",
    "1": "1|2,2|3",
    "2": "3|4",
    "3": "4|5"
  }, {
    "0": "WBC",
    "1": "",
    "2": "5|6",
    "3": "6|7"
  }, {
    "0": "Neutrophils",
    "1": "",
    "2": "",
    "3": "6|8"
  }];

  $scope.headers = [{
    "field": "0",
    "displayName": "Lab",
    "pinnable": true,
    "pinned": true,
    "width": 160
  }, {
    "field": "1",
    "displayName": "8/1/2014 (week 1)",
    "pinnable": false,
    "width": 160,
    "cellTemplate": "<div class=\"ngCellText\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\"><span ng-cell-text><div lab-val labdata=\"row.getProperty(col.field)\"></div></span></div>"
  }, {
    "field": "2",
    "displayName": "8/8/2014 (week 2)",
    "pinnable": false,
    "width": 160,
    "cellTemplate": "<div class=\"ngCellText\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\"><span ng-cell-text><div lab-val labdata=\"row.getProperty(col.field)\"></div></span></div>"
  }, {
    "field": "3",
    "displayName": "8/15/2014 (week 3)",
    "pinnable": false,
    "width": 160,
    "cellTemplate": "<div class=\"ngCellText\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\"><span ng-cell-text><div lab-val labdata=\"row.getProperty(col.field)\"></div></span></div>"
  }];

  $scope.baselineLabsGridOptions = {
    data: 'data',
    enablePinning: true,
    enablePaging: false,
    showFooter: false,
    columnDefs: 'headers',
    showSelectionCheckbox: false
  };

  $scope.edit = function(id, val) {
    $("#result").text(val);
  };
});

app.directive('labVal', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      labdata: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      scope.$watch('labdata', function(newval) {
        var arrVals = scope.labdata.split(',');
        var retArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrVals.length; i++) {
          var valArr = arrVals[i].split('|');
          if (valArr.length > 1)
            retArr.push('<a ng-click="edit(' + valArr[0] + ',\'' + valArr[1] + '\')">' + valArr[1] + '</a>');
          else
            retArr.push('<span>&nbsp;</span>');
        }
        var el = angular.element(retArr.join(", "));
        var compiled = $compile(el);
        elem.append(el);
        compiled(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Html:

```
  <head>
    <link data-require="ng-grid@*" data-semver="2.0.9" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.9/ng-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-grid@*" data-semver="2.0.9" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-grid/2.0.9/ng-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="modalGridStyle" data-ng-grid="baselineLabsGridOptions"></div>
    <div id="result">Nothing yet!</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-click doesn't know what `edit()` is. That function only exists on the controller scope, and because you are isolating the directive scope, it won't know how to access it.

When declaring your directive, you can add an additional variable to your scope:

```
scope: {
  labdata: '=',
  edit: '='
}
```

And then on your grid template, just pass the controller edit function:

```
<div class='ngCellText' ng-class='col.colIndex()'>
   <span ng-cell-text>
     <div lab-val labdata='row.getProperty(col.field)' edit='edit'></div>
   </span>
 </div>"
```

Comment: You can also explicitly call the parent's function `ng-click="$parent.edit('`